# Invalidate and create new instance of timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a timer that i am running from within a closure to help perform some ui update (progress bar).  It works for the first item, but i want it to work for multiple items.  So each time the closure is run a new instance of the timer is run and the new userInfo.

```
    // dispatch and add run loop to get it to fire
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(self.downloadTimer(_:)), userInfo: [innerCell, collectionView, indexPath], repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    })
```

When this function below is finished i want the timer to be recreated and pass new userInfo to the selector..

```
func downloadTimer(_ timer: Timer) {

    // need to pass arguments to timer as array inside userInfo
    // then create dictionary and extract

    let dict = timer.userInfo as! NSArray
    let cell = dict[0] as! InnerCollectionCell
    let collectionView = dict[1] as! UICollectionView
    let indexPath = dict[2] as! IndexPath


    // the index path isnt getting reset

    // without casting the progress bar in each cell was displaying when coming back to DownloadCollectionController
    if let downloadingCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? InnerCollectionCell {

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            downloadingCell.progressBar.isHidden = false
            downloadingCell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.progressBar)
            downloadingCell.progressBar.setProgress(downloadProgress, animated: true)
            downloadingCell.setNeedsDisplay()


            if downloadProgress >= 1.0 {
                print("TIMER STOPPED")
                downloadingCell.progressBar.isHidden = true
                //downloadQueue.operations[0].cancel()
                timer.invalidate()
                collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

            }
        })
    }

}
```

The closure containing the timer = Timer is re-run but the new user info is not passed to the timer, it just keeps running with the original userInfo.  If i invalidate the timer it can no longer be fired?

Ive tried creating it locally to the initial firing:

```
var timer = Timer()
timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(self.downloadTimer(_:)), userInfo: [innerCell, collectionView, indexPath], repeats: true)
```

But it doesn't recreate the timer and i want to be able to stop it if the user leaves the viewcontroller.

Is there a better way of achieving this?  I know your not supposed to be able to retire a timer.  there must be a way of creating a unique instance of it each time.

---- EDIT ----

This is what the index paths print as:

```
[0, 5]
[0, 5]
[0, 5]

[0, 5]
[0, 2]
[0, 5]
[0, 2]

[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```

So its taking a while to invalidate the timer and in that time the timer has been re-fired and the function is using the old index path until progress = 1

---- EDIT ----

The only place invalidation takes place is when progress >= 1

```
            if downloadProgress >= 1.0 {
                timer.invalidate()
                downloadingCell.progressBar.isHidden = true
                downloadingCell.progressBar.progress = 0
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
```

Then because the timer is fired from cellForItemAt if the cell meets certain conditions, when collectionView.reloadData() is called the timer should be re-validated and the updated userInfo sent.

So this is the block inside cellForItemAt:

```
for operation in downloadQueue.operations {
        if operation.name == self.multiPartArray[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item].name  {
            // edits for all queued operations
            innerCell.spinner.isHidden = false
            innerCell.spinner.startAnimating()
            innerCell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: innerCell.spinner)
            innerCell.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
            innerCell.spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray

        // hide the progress on all in queue it will be pushed to front when needed
        innerCell.progressBar.isHidden = true

        if operation.name == downloadQueue.operations[0].name {
            // edits for the active downlaod in queue

            // hide the spinner for currently downloading cell
            // innerCell.spinner.isHidden = true
            innerCell.spinner.isHidden = false
            innerCell.spinner.startAnimating()
            innerCell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: innerCell.spinner)
            innerCell.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
            innerCell.spinner.color = UIColor.blue

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.downloadTimer(_:)), userInfo: [innerCell, collectionView, indexPath, collectionView.tag], repeats: true)
                    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
                })

            break
        } else {
            // edits spinner that isnt currently downloading
            innerCell.progressBar.isHidden = true
            innerCell.spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
        }
    } else {
        // edits the spinner that isnt in queue
        innerCell.progressBar.isHidden = true
        innerCell.spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
    }
}
```

I realise its not the most elegant solution but I've got nested collection views that have probably not been set up entirely properly so ill settle for a work around in this case.

And the downloadTimer:

```
func downloadTimer(_ timer: Timer) {

    // need to pass arguments to timer as array inside userInfo
    // then create dictionary and extract
    let dict = timer.userInfo as! NSArray
    let cell = dict[0] as! InnerCollectionCell
    let collectionView = dict[1] as! UICollectionView
    let indexPath = dict[2] as! IndexPath
    let tag = dict[3] as! Int

    print(indexPath)

    // without casting the progress bar in each cell was displaying when coming back to DownloadCollectionController
    if let downloadingCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? InnerCollectionCell {

       // self.outerCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: tag, section: 0)])

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            downloadingCell.spinner.isHidden = true
            downloadingCell.progressBar.isHidden = false
            downloadingCell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.progressBar)
            downloadingCell.progressBar.setProgress(downloadProgress, animated: true)
            downloadingCell.setNeedsDisplay()

            if downloadProgress >= 1.0 {
                timer.invalidate()
                downloadingCell.progressBar.isHidden = true
                downloadingCell.progressBar.progress = 0
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to schedule and use a time is like this:

```
//schedules timer at an 4 seconds interval + pass desired userInfo 
var myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0
        , target: self, selector: #selector(timerSelector), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//timer selector peform your actions there and  
func timerSelector(dt:Timer){  
}

//invalidate timer when needed like this
myTimer?.invalidate()
```

Also to reschedule the timer just call again `Timer.scheduledTimer`

Comment: Its taking a while to invalidate. Ive edited question to show some prints of the indexPath that I'm passing to the timer.

Comment: printing is not an accurate way to show the time some execution takes ... but probably it is a bit slow because you are doing some extra execution, can you please edit your post to show where and how you invalidate and reschedule the timer, because it seems you are only invalidating when `downloadProgress >= 1.0` ?

Comment: have edited post.  I understand this isnt ideal setup but its what I'm working with at the moment.

Comment: yes it is not the best set-up ... what I would suggest, because the timer is cell related, in your `InnerCollectionCell ` you should handle the timer operations, this way you won't have to call `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` so you will have less operations, also as said above, the timer won't be fired again until `downloadProgress >= 1`, so if that is a problem try to maybe rethink some of the login in how and when you use the timer